# How to detect which content is not secured on mixed content SSL page.?

Tags: security

I've added a SSL certificate to an existing site, and now in IE I get a mixed content warning. Problem is, I don't know what's the non-secure content IE is warning me about. It's a simple html page, with a few Flash, a few images, a loaded CSS and JS.

How can I find out what's the non-secured content..?

Edit:

**I found the culprit: it's the JS AC_RunActiveContent.js used to display Flash movie. So anyone has an idea on how to prevent SSL mixed content when using AC_RunActiveContent.js.?**

Comment: For starters go to the page and click "View Source".  Then do a search for `http://` any results are non secure

Comment: I did that. I now found out that it's AC_RunActiveContent.js that is causing the mixed content warning...  Will post a solution if I find one...

Comment: perhaps change the name of your question, since it makes it seem as though you are seeking a general solution for figuring out these cases

Answer (score 3):

This means that something is requesting content using the `http` protocol specifically, or you have an absolute path to an image or other content that begins with `http` instead of `https`.

A few tips: Use relative paths everywhere you can.  If you must use an absolute path, and it's to a server you own, use `https`.  If you're loading stuff from off your site, you're probably stuck with the mixed-content warning.

This also goes for your scripts, check out the JS, and the CSS template and make sure they're not the guilty parties - if they are change them to use relative paths, or to request items via `https` instead of `http` (assuming you're positive that the server they're referencing supports `https`, if it doesn't you're stuck).

There are a few other details, [this](http://www.zorked.com/security/ie-mixed-content-secure-nonsecure-items/) might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so here is the solution for my particular problem. It was the codebase value in my code that needed to be https as well (I didn't think it would trigger the warning, as my Flash were displaying correctly, oh well)...

```
AC_FL_RunContent( 'codebase','https://download.macromedia.com/pub/shoc...
```

Link to Adobe info on this: [Security Information error in Internet Explorer](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/165/tn_16588.html)

Answer (score 2):

I use the Firefox console -- it reports the http resources it blocks from fetching on a mixed content page.

Answer (score 0):

Search your source for http: only. Another great tool to help you out is [Fiddler](https://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) with which you can see what's getting downloaded upon requesting your page.